# Understand Post/Redirect/Get in PHP.

Tags: php, forms, post

I would like to understand Post/Redirect/Get for my particular case.

I have a search page.
http://nariku.weebee.be/search.php. (This site is still in developement).

Make a "Recherche par code postal", you go to **result.php**. Click on a name to go to **pro-about.php** My problem is, if you click on browser back button, you go to Document Expired.

How can I fix this? PRG? Use session?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903227/search-results-and-the-back-button-html-forms) might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Use GET was the solution.